# Query in objectdb

Tags: java, sql, database, objectdb

I have to implement a query in objectdb and have very little idea.

The problem is to write a query which

```
Returns the collection of all laptops each of which has at least one
          other laptop preinstalled with the same processor.
```

My Laptop class is

```
public class Laptop {

    String modelName; // key
    int price;        // in dollars
    boolean hasHDScreen; // has a HD Screen ?
    int hardDriveCapacity; // in GB

    Processor processor;  // the preinstalled processor
    Memory memory; // the preinstalled memory
    Company madeBy; // the inverse of company.makeLaptops
}
```

and my processor class is

```
public class Processor {

    String modelName; // key 
    float clockSpeed; // in gigahertz (GHz)

    Company madeBy; // the inverse of Company.makeProcessors
}
```

Also my function definition looks like below

```
public static Collection<Laptop> sameProcessor(Query q) {
        /* Returns the collection of all laptops each of which has at least one
         * other laptop preinstalled with the same processor.
         */
        q.setClass(Laptop.class);
        q.setFilter("this.processor == ");

    }
```

How can I achieve it ? SQL would be fine as well.

Thanks

Comment: @ant: But query in hibernate can also be handy. Because then I can try to convert it into JAVA and hence in ObjectDb query language

Answer (score 1):

Finally got over this one. Here's the solution

```
public static Collection<Laptop> sameProcessor(Query q) {
        /* Returns the collection of all laptops each of which has at least one
         * other laptop preinstalled with the same processor.
         */

        Collection result = new HashSet<Laptop>();
        q.setClass(Laptop.class);

        Collection allLaptops = (Collection) q.execute();

        Iterator it = allLaptops.iterator();

        while(it.hasNext()) {
            Laptop currentLaptop = ((Laptop)it.next());
            Processor p = currentLaptop.processor;
            if(p.installedOn(q).size()>=2) {

                result.add(currentLaptop);
            }
        }

        return (Collection<Laptop>)result;       
    }
```

The method used `installedOn` definition is below:

```
public Collection<Laptop> installedOn(Query q) {

     /* Returns the collection of all laptops on which the target memory 
        is preinstalled. Represents the inverse of Laptop.memory.
     */
        Memory memory = this;
        q.setClass(Laptop.class);
        q.declareParameters("Memory m");
        q.setFilter("this.memory == m");
        Collection result = (Collection)q.execute(memory);
        return (Collection<Laptop>) result;

    }
```

Thanks. Hope it helps.